# java: How to copy a directory in a jar file to a tmp dir?

Tags: java, jar, directory, copy

I know how to create a temporary directory in Java, but is there an easy way to copy files in Java from the jar file to this directory?

```
File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
File helpDir = new File(tmpDir, "myApp-help");
helpDir.createNewFile(); // oops, this isn't right, I want to create a dir
URL helpURL = getClass().getResource("/help-info");  

/* ???? I want to copy the files from helpURL to helpDir */

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
URI helpURI = /* some URI from the new dir's index.html */
desktop.browse(helpURI);
```

Comment: hmm, may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377104/how-to-extract-a-folder-from-jar

Answer (score 1):

Apache's `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` can do that for you

To create directory use `File.mkdir();`

Convert URL to File with `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.toFile(URL)`

use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile()` to copy.

Comment: It isn't his directory can't be handled like file, because it is inside the JAR.

Comment: My mistake, i thought that he has the resources in the `war`, so that they are already extracted by the deployer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the command `jar tf [here your jarfile]`. This will list the contents of the JAR Archive with their full path, relative to the jarfile (1 line = 1 file). Check if the line starts with the path of the directory you want to extract, and use `Class.getResourceAsStream(URL)`  for the matching lines and extract them to your temporary folder.

Here is an example output of `jar tf`:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
TicTacToe.class
audio/
audio/beep.au
audio/ding.au
audio/return.au
audio/yahoo1.au
audio/yahoo2.au
images/
images/cross.gif
images/not.gif
```